# Is there a single place I can see all the app reviews I've written in the iOS App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Short of individually tapping on "Write a Review" for all the apps I've ever purchased, is there any place (on the web, in iTunes, or in a third-party app) I can view all the reviews that I've written for apps on the iOS App Store?

If that is not possible, can I obtain a list of the apps for which I've written reviews?

Comment: @IconDaemon http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/failing#failing__6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the App Store tap on your face in the top right corner, then tap on your account (has your name and email on it), then tap "Ratings and Reviews"

[image: App Store]
[image: Apple ID]
[image: Ratings and Reviews]

Comment: Ah yes, that is the obvious place for it. Goodjob, Apple. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance of an update for the new App Store in iOS 11? Or should I ask that as a new question?

Comment: @Rich I've updated the answer to reflect the changes in iOS 11.

Comment: Wow that's a super-speedy edit. My face is for some reason a basketball, which helps explain why I couldn't find it this time. Thanks for taking the time to update your answer; I feel a bit bad for not asking a new question because it occurs to me now I can't upvote/accept it again. :(